# How to $watch but only update a model on an event from another controller

Tags: angularjs

I have two partials and two controllers and some data in `$localstorage`. One of them is a header that displays user data and the other is a user profile data entry screen. When that screen saves it updates `$localstorage`.

When they click <kbd>OK</kbd> on the data entry screen, I want the data in the header to update.

Right now I have a `$watch` over the `$localstorage` in the header which recopies that into `$scope.user` (which the partial is bound to), and it's working to keep the header updated, but:

- It updates the header character by character as they type. This causes a delay when they type each character, and it's a strange UX.
- It updates the header even if they don't click <kbd>OK</kbd> to save the changes

I don't know how to hook up an event from one controller to another, and even if I did, I don't know how to say "refresh the model" inside the header controller.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do both the controllers sit in one parent controller?

Comment: @IfTrue, no, they don't. Thanks. I was able to make the GPicazo answer work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't really providing any code to show how you are binding to `$localStorage`, so here is some pseudocode that you can adapt to your implementation:

```
// -- IN THE DATA ENTRY CONTROLLER --

// at the beginning, get a copy of the $localstorage profile data and assign it
// to the scope variable that will be bound to your view
$scope.profileData = angular.copy($localStorage.get('...')); 

// all your changes will be made to the $scope.profileData during editing.
// this will not affect $localStorage since we created a copy.

$scope.onOk = function() {
    // on save, make a copy of the edited profile and push that to $localStorage.
    // At that point, the watch on your header controller should pick up the changes.
    $localStorage.set('...', angular.copy($scope.profileData));
};
```

Comment: I see what you are trying to do. You are trying to quantize the changes into discreet OK events. Let me verify this is the issue; give me a few minutes. Thanks!

Comment: `angular.copy` was the key to the solution. You nailed it. I didn't have to do it on the `set`, but it is definitely needed on the `get`.

Comment: Glad that fixed it for you.